# Enable multiple select in GridView with custom data source

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, webforms

I have this `GridView` that uses a custom data source:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="DateManager" runat="server" />

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="setDate" runat="server" 
    UpdateMode="Conditional" 
    ChildrenAsTriggers="true">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:GridView ID="res" runat="server" 
            AutoGenerateColumns="False"
            CellPadding="4"
            ForeColor="#333333"
            GridLines="None"
            Width="600px" 
            AllowPaging="True">
            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />

            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Ty" HeaderText="Type" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="time" HeaderText="Time" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="duration" HeaderText="Duration" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="confirmed" HeaderText="Status" />
                <asp:CommandField SelectText="SelectIt" ShowSelectButton="True" />
            </Columns>

            <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />
            <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
            <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F5F7FB" />
            <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6D95E1" />
            <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9EBEF" />
            <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4870BE" />
        </asp:GridView>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

How can I enable multiple select on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `CheckBox` near evey row like code below and select multiple lines.

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="RowLevelCheckBox" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

For detailed information check these articles : [Article1](https://web.archive.org/web/20210316002334/http://aspnet.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/053106-1.aspx) [Article2](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/202938/How-to-select-multiple-records-from-the-GridView-a)

Comment: Any way without using additional item?

Comment: as far as i know there's no way to make it without additional item